# What programming languages support implicit interface implementation by delegation?

Tags: interface, delegates, decorator, kotlin

Kotlin can do this very neat trick:

```
 class Derived(b: Base) : Base by b
```

which makes your class `Derived` implement `Base`, and all methods of `Base` not implemented explicitly in `Derived` are automatically delegated to member `b`. I don't program in Kotlin and losing `'this'` pointer may be quite limiting, but it looks like such a simple thing that can mean tons for maintainability that every language should have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some languages with Delegates :

- [Xtend](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.8/org/eclipse/xtend/lib/annotations/Delegate.html)
- [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)
- [Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Delegate.html)
- All languages that allow overwriting some sort of Missing Method, can easily implement delegation (using what is normally called `missing method proxy`): i.e.: Ruby, Python, JavaScript es6, Smalltalk

An example of missing method proxy using Ruby ( taken from [here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/08/07/patterns-are-not-scary-method-missing-proxy/) ):

```
class Proxy
      def initialize(subject)
    @subject = subject
  end

  private
    def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
      @subject.send(method, *args, &block)
    end
end

proxied_array = Proxy.new([1,2,3])
puts proxied_array.size # 3
```

Comment: Nice, I haven't even heard about XTend before and  Swift suddenly seems more interesting than just 'me too' I'll have to think of a project to code it in it. As for others, I was primarily interested in strongly statically typed languages and implementing in a declarative sense rather than just delegating, but it's nice to be remembered about the advantages of script languages, too.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi [has implements keyword](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_Implements_for_Delegation)

```
  IMyIntf = interface
     procedure DoWork1();
     procedure DoWork2();
     ...
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyIntf)
  private
    FIntf: IMyIntf;
  public
    property Prop: IMyIntf read FIntf implements IMyIntf;
  end;
```